# Simply if else condition in JavaScript/es6

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

How do I make this if else more simple.

```
if (!request) {
  return 'no request';
} else {
  if (loading === '404') {
    return 'rejected';
  }
  if (loading === '200' && !array1.length) {
    return 'fulfilled';
  }
}
```

if any ternary operator then how can I make it

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? It's clear as is, you don't need to minify your developement code.

Comment: I don't think it can be much simpler than this. Each condition is different, and each return statement is different

Comment: not all paths lead to a returned value so not sure how a ternary would work.

Comment: Cannot make it simpler, but you miss a return in the `else condition`. What if all the condition is not fullfilled? I think you should return something if nothing fullfilled.

Comment: The code is working I guess, so the better site to ask help would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Other than that if you have `return` in `if` you don't need `else` this convention would flatten your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could omit else part, because you return if `true`.

```
if (!request) return 'no request';
if (loading === '404') return 'rejected';
if (loading === '200' && !array1.length) return 'fulfilled';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do this with the ternary operator. Hope the below code will you.

```
!request ? 'no request' : loading === '404' ? 'rejected' : 'fullfilled'
```

Comment: Nested ternaries are almost always bad practice though.

Comment: @NullDev you should explain why do you believe smth is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if-elseif-else` statement

```
if(!request) return 'no request'
else if(loading === '404') return 'rejected'
else if(loading === '200' && !array.length) return 'fulfilled'
```

Comment: There is no need to use `else if` if you have `return`. If you remove redundant code the answer would be identical to the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

one might consider ...

```
{
  // ...
  return ((!request && 'no request')
    || (loading === '404' && 'rejected')
    || (loading === '200' && !array1.length && 'fulfilled')
    || undefined // or 'failure' // or 'not fulfilled'
  );
}
```

... or ...

```
{
  // ...
  let returnValue = (!request && 'no request')
    || (loading === '404' && 'rejected')
    || (loading === '200' && !array1.length && 'fulfilled')
    || undefined; // or 'failure'; // or 'not fulfilled';
  
  // do more stuff ...
  // ...
  // ... maybe even change `returnValue` again.
  
  return returnValue;      
}
```

Comment: I think that this style is very useful in more standard code bases: Like if you have 5+ of loading, and they all return a string, then this code is perfect. If those three if statements are all there is however, then this code is extremely difficult to dig through. Just an opinion.

Comment: btw, no need to wrap logical AND expressions with parentheses. the main difference to the question is the place. `if` statements could be at any place, but the `return` statement unconditionally ends the function.

Answer (score -1):

```js
if (request) {
  switch (loading) {
    case "404":
      return "rejected";
    case "200":
      if (!array1.length) return "filfilled";
      break;
  }
} else {
  return "no request";
}
```

I think a switch statement is better here considering that you may get more cases.

Comment: Please no, for the sake of cyclomatic complexity :)